# Fill forms from extension on Google Chrome iOS

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, google-chrome, xamarin

I made a password manager for iOS and It has an extension that is used to fill forms in Safari. In the extension I use `NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingFile` property to specify my javascript file that needs to be executed. It works perfectly in Safari but in Chrome it doesn't work at all. Looks like it doesn't even execute the javascript.

I searched a lot on the web but didn't find a lot of documentation about this.

I was wondering what I need to do in order to made it work in Chrome? I tried 1Password and their extension works perfectly in chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like we only need to send the username and password to chrome and it will automatically handle the data for you.

```
- (IBAction)done {
  NSDictionary* loginDictionary = @{
    @"username" : @"john.doe@gmail.com",
    @"password" : @"super!secret"
  };
  NSItemProvider* itemProvider =
      [[NSItemProvider alloc] initWithItem:loginDictionary
                            typeIdentifier:(NSString*)kUTTypePropertyList];
  NSExtensionItem* extensionItem = [[NSExtensionItem alloc] init];
  [extensionItem setAttachments:@[ itemProvider ]];

  [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:@[ extensionItem ]
                                     completionHandler:nil];
}
```

Thanks to [pkl's post](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=405894) from the chromium forum.